# listbox search delete and add

Tags: c#, listbox

I have two listbox I want to place randomly on other listbox I want to keep the searchString out of random I want to add first listbox.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] names = new string[12];
        names[0] = "Item 0";
        names[1] = "Item 1";
        names[2] = "Item 2";
        names[3] = "Item 3";
        names[4] = "Item 4";
        names[5] = "Item 5";
        names[6] = "Item 6";
        names[7] = "Item 7";
        names[8] = "Item 8";
        names[9] = "Item 9";
        names[10] = "Item 10";
        names[11] = "Item 11";
        this.LB_1.Items.AddRange(names);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchString = "Item 3";

        int number = LB_1.Items.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            //if (LB_1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(searchString))
            //{

            //    LB_2.Items.Add(searchString);
            //    //i cant add and delete LB_1 seached item
            //}
            Random rdn = new Random();
            int rnd = rdn.Next(0, LB_1.Items.Count);
            LB_2.Items.Add(LB_1.Items[rnd]);
            LB_1.Items.RemoveAt(rnd);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use an array.  Use a BindingList<T> as a DataSource of the ListBox.  If you delete more than one item, you would have to loop backwards to preserve the indexes.

Comment: Create one and only one Random instance for your entire app - not inside a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchString = "Item 3";
        LB_2.Items.Add(searchString);
        Random rdn = new Random();

        while (LB_1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            int rnd = rdn.Next(0, LB_1.Items.Count);
            if (LB_1.Items[rnd].ToString() != searchString) LB_2.Items.Add(LB_1.Items[rnd]);
            LB_1.Items.RemoveAt(rnd);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. it wasn't exactly what I wanted I don't want to out of the "item 3" on list. I want it in the first place